# ¿Qué significa la palabra "tirada" en Argentina?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario, argentina

En Argentina he visto que utilizan la palabra *tirada* para algún evento, pero no sé cuál es exactamente el uso. O sea, he escuchado que dicen:

> ¿Vamos a la tirada de la Marti?
>
> ¿Me invitaron a una tirada, vamos?

¿Alguien me dice lo que es?

Comment: Parece ser una fiesta, pero tal definición no se recoge en el diccionario de americanismos ni en el diccionario de la lengua.  De hecho, en el DA *tirada* significa una mala pasada, que parece ser el contrario.

Answer (score 3):

#### TL;DR:

> Es una "tirada" de huevos. Marti cumple los 15 así que van los amigos a su casa y le tiran huevos, harina y demás. Se usa acá en Mendoza.

#### Post original:

Por el contexto, coincido con guifa en que parece que se refieren a una fiesta. En todo caso, debe de ser un neologismo bastante reciente y usado en la expresión oral principalmente.

He encontrado estos textos escritos en el [CORPES XXI](http://www.rae.es/recursos/banco-de-datos/corpes-xxi) (negritas mías):

> *Tamara tiene laburo, eh. Atendió a cinco personas, no sé cuánto cobra la **tirada** pero para un sábado no está mal, aunque a lo mejor es como las peluquerías que los sábados trabajan más.*
>
> Carlos Ardohain, "Los incógnitos", 2011 (Argentina).
>
> ---
>
> *¿Sabés que es soltera? Tenía un escote muy generoso, bueno... usted sabe que a mí me gustan las mujeres contundentes, ¿no? Me dijo lo de la **tirada** gratis, quedamos en que el miércoles me la hace, que es el día en que estamos los dos, así no tengo que dejar solo el local.*
>
> Carlos Ardohain, "Los incógnitos", 2011 (Argentina).

En estos ejemplos, sacados del mismo libro, parece que *tirada* se refiere a *servicio* o *trabajo*, y más concretamente yo diría que a un servicio sexual. A fin de cuentas, "tirada" es la acción de "[tirar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Zr3ZJPx)", y este verbo usado como pronominal ("tirarse") significa "poseer sexualmente a alguien". [Nota: [en Reddit aclaran](https://www.reddit.com/r/argentina/comments/66no8q/qu%C3%A9_significa_la_palabra_tirada_en_argentina/dgk3o6e/) que se refiere a una felación.]

Si es así, no veo demasiado descabellado que al ser una palabra de carácter "festivo" se haya expandido su significado hasta significar "fiesta" en general. A menos que no se refiera a una "fiesta" cualquiera, sino a una orgía...

He preguntado en todo caso en el Reddit de Argentina (aunque primero me tienen que aceptar el *post*). Si mis sospechas se confirman, los comentarios allí pueden ser de lo más divertido...

---

Más averiguaciones:

- Según el *Diccionario de americanismos*, la voz *tirársele (a alguien)* significa en Argentina "hacerle una declaración amorosa a una persona". Así que "una tirada" podría ser una fiesta de pedida de mano, o algo así.

---

Primeros comentarios de Reddit:

- El primer comentario dice que al ver la frase automáticamente pensó en una tirada de cerveza artesanal, pero que puede que no sea eso. Mucho me temo que para entender la palabra vamos a necesitar un contexto más detallado.
- Acaba de aparecer [un comentario](https://www.reddit.com/r/argentina/comments/66no8q/qu%C3%A9_significa_la_palabra_tirada_en_argentina/dgk1qj1/) que puede que haya dado en el clavo (negritas mías *one more time*):

  > **Es una "tirada" de huevos.** Marti cumple los 15 así que van los amigos a su casa y le tiran huevos, harina y demás. Se usa acá en Mendoza.

  Aquí tienes [un artículo de prensa](http://www.diariouno.com.ar/pais/cada-vez-son-mas-violentos-los-ritos-los-cumpleanos-20151129-n37719.html) que habla sobre lo violentos que se están volviendo los ritos al cumplir los 15 allí en Argentina, y hablan de "la tirada".

  > “La tirada”, destinada a chicas que cumplen 15 años, consiste en preparar mezclas desagradables que incluyen productos vencidos o podridos, huevos, vinagre, sumado en algunos casos, caca de perros y pis de algunos de los adolescentes.

Comment: En Argentina existe el evento de arrojarle huevos etc. a alguien para festejar su graduación universitaria. No sabía que se había extendido a las quinceañeras. En todo caso es la primera vez que leo que tiene un nombre propio. Hace unos doscientos y pico de años que no participo en fiestas de quince y puede ser que no esté informado pero creo que es un neologismo y no sé si se comprenda mucho fuera de cierta franja de edad.

Comment: Como argentino (de la región NOA) no reconozco el término en la acepción de rito quinceañero,  —aparentemente cuyano, porque el articlulo citado es de un diario de Mendoza. Si acaso es reconocible en la connotación sexual (de "tirar" el miembro masculino). También "tirar" (ya no sustantivado así) puede aludir a "acostar", tener sexo con alguien